# While Overloading The << Operator Was It Correctly Formatted?

Tags: c++, class, operators, overloading

I have been getting outputs and sometimes even getting the complete output, however I don't quite understand why I'd be getting said outputs. I want to believe it has something to do with my overloading of said operator "<<" when I perform the operation of outputting the information in the "OpenSea" object. Any leads would be tremendously helpful and thank you for your time!

*Note:* I included only the necessary files but will update if you think you need more to understand the full scope of my situation. Also there is no need to give me tips on how to format my code as I know a lot of it can be reworked for optimization.

***main.cpp***

```
#include "aquaClasses.h"
#include "aquaFish.h"
#include "aquaKillerWhale.h"
#include "aquaPenguin.h"
#include "aquaSea.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  srand (time (NULL));
  // Simulation
  Sea OpenSea (17, 17);
  cout << OpenSea;
}
```

***aquaClasses.h*** <-- "main" header file

```
#ifndef AQUACLASSES_H
#define AQUACLASSES_H

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

// Constants
const short int AMT_FISH = 200;
const short int AMT_KWHALES = 2;
const short int AMT_PENGS = 50;
const short int MAX_SIM_INTERATIONS = 10000;
const short int MAX_SEA_GRID = 25;
const short int MAX_SEA_SIZE = 625;

// Functions
template <typename TYPE> int calculate_distance (int obj1_x, int obj1_y,
                                                 TYPE obj2);
template <typename TYPE> int calculate_direction (int obj1_x, int obj1_y,
                                                  TYPE obj2);

#endif
```

***aquaSea.h***

```
#ifndef AQUASEA_H
#define AQUASEA_H

// Forward Declarations to circumvent circular dependency
class Fish;
class Penguin;
class Killer_Whale;

class Sea
{
  private:
    char m_grid [MAX_SEA_GRID][MAX_SEA_GRID];
    int m_fish;
    int m_kwhales;
    int m_pengs;
    int m_size;
    int m_height;
    int m_width;
    void clear ();
    void populate ();
  public:
    Sea (const int grid_size_height, const int grid_size_width);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Sea obj);
    int getHeight () const {return m_height;};
    int getWidth () const {return m_width;};
    void setCell (int obj_x, int obj_y, char cell_symbol);
    // Appropriate accessor/mutator functions
};

#endif
```

***aquaSea.cpp***

```
#include "aquaClasses.h"
#include "aquaFish.h"
#include "aquaPenguin.h"
#include "aquaKillerWhale.h"
#include "aquaSea.h"

using namespace std;

//  - [row][column]
Sea::Sea (const int grid_size_height, const int grid_size_width)
{
  m_fish = 200;
  m_kwhales = 2;
  m_pengs = 50;

  if ((grid_size_height || grid_size_width) <= 0)
  {
    if (grid_size_height <= 0 && grid_size_width > 0)
    {
      m_size = MAX_SEA_GRID * grid_size_width;
      m_width = grid_size_width;
      m_height = MAX_SEA_GRID;
    }
    else if (grid_size_width <= 0 && grid_size_height > 0)
    {
      m_size = MAX_SEA_GRID * grid_size_height;
      m_width = MAX_SEA_GRID;
      m_height = grid_size_height;
    }
    else if (grid_size_height <= 0 && grid_size_width <= 0)
    {
      m_size = MAX_SEA_GRID * MAX_SEA_GRID;
      m_height = MAX_SEA_GRID;
      m_width = MAX_SEA_GRID;
    }
  }
  else
    {
      m_size = grid_size_height * grid_size_width;
      m_height = grid_size_height;
      m_width = grid_size_width;
    }
  clear ();
  populate ();
}


ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Sea obj)
{
  os << "Sea Height: " << obj.m_width << endl << "Sea Wdith: "
     << obj.m_width << endl << "Sea Size: " << obj.m_size
     << endl;
  os << "Grid View: " << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < obj.m_height; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < obj.m_width; j++)
    {
      os << obj.m_grid [i][j];
    }
    os << endl;
  }
  return os;
}

void Sea::clear ()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < m_height; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < m_width; j++)
    {
      m_grid[i][j] = 'O';
    }
  }
  return;
}

void Sea::populate ()
{
  // Special simluation variables
  bool applyFish = true;
  bool applyKWhales = false;
  bool applyPengs = false;
  int amtFishPop = 35;
  int amtKWhalesPop = 2;
  int amtPengPop = 20;
  int index = 0;
  int randGridRow = 0;
  int randGridCol = 0;
  int totalPop = amtFishPop + amtKWhalesPop + amtPengPop;
  Fish arr_fish [AMT_FISH];
  Killer_Whale arr_kwhales [AMT_KWHALES];
  Penguin arr_pengs [AMT_PENGS];

  for (int i = 0; i < totalPop; i++)
  {
    // Grab random place on grid to apply and check if grid plot is open
    randGridRow = rand () % 16;
    randGridCol = rand () % 16;

    while (m_grid [randGridRow][randGridCol] != 'O')
    {
      randGridRow = rand () % 16;
      randGridCol = rand () % 16;
    }

    // Populate and Update Fish
    if (amtFishPop > 0 && applyFish == true)
    {
      arr_fish[index].setX (randGridCol);
      arr_fish[index].setY (randGridRow);
      setCell (arr_fish[index].getX (), arr_fish[index].getY (), 'F');
      amtFishPop--;
      index++;
    }
    else if (amtFishPop == 0)
    {
      applyFish = false;
      applyKWhales = true;
      index = 0;
    }

    // Populate and Update Killer Whales
    if (amtKWhalesPop > 0 && applyKWhales == true)
    {
      arr_kwhales[index].setX (randGridCol);
      arr_kwhales[index].setY (randGridRow);
      setCell (arr_kwhales[index].getX (), arr_kwhales[index].getY (), 'K');
      amtKWhalesPop--;
      index++;
    }
    else if (amtKWhalesPop == 0)
    {
      applyKWhales = false;
      applyPengs = true;
      index = 0;
    }

    // Populate and Update Penguins
    if (amtPengPop > 0 && applyPengs == true)
    {
      arr_pengs[index].setX (randGridCol);
      arr_pengs[index].setY (randGridRow);
      setCell (arr_pengs[index].getX (), arr_pengs[index].getY (), 'P');
      amtPengPop--;
      index++;
    }
    else if (amtPengPop == 0)
    {
      applyPengs = false;
      index = 0;
    }
  }

  return;
}

void Sea::setCell (int obj_x, int obj_y, char cell_symbol)
{ 
  m_grid [obj_x][obj_y] = cell_symbol;

  return;
}
```

***Types of Output***
Wanted:
 - [Image](https://imgur.com/a/CXW9Q)
Unwanted:
 - [Image](https://imgur.com/a/hBQCb)
***STOP! AFTER THIS POINT IS OPTIONAL CODE TO FURTHER UNDERSTAND THE SITUATION***

***Other Code Of Reference If You Want But I Don't Think It's Needed***

***aquaFish.h***

```
#ifndef AQUAFISH_H
#define AQUAFISH_H

class Fish
{
  private:
    int m_fish_amt_food;
    int m_fish_x;
    int m_fish_y;
    bool m_fish_alive;
  public:
    Fish ();
    int getX () const {return m_fish_x;};
    int getY () const {return m_fish_y;};
    void setX (int new_x) {m_fish_x = new_x;};
    void setY (int new_y) {m_fish_y = new_y;};
    int getFishAmtFood () const {return m_fish_amt_food;};
    void move ();
};

#endif
```

***aquaFish.cpp***

```
#include "aquaClasses.h"
#include "aquaFish.h"

using namespace std;

Fish::Fish ()
{
  int randNum = rand () % 10 + 1;
  m_fish_amt_food = randNum;
  m_fish_x = -1;
  m_fish_y = -1;
}

void Fish::move ()
{
  int randDir = rand () % 8 + 1;
  if (randDir == 1)
  {
    m_fish_y++;
  }
  else if (randDir == 2)
  {
    m_fish_x++;
    m_fish_y++;
  }
  else if (randDir == 3)
  {
    m_fish_x++;
  }
  else if (randDir == 4)
  {
    m_fish_x++;
    m_fish_y--;
  }
  else if (randDir == 5)
  {
    m_fish_y--;
  }
  else if (randDir == 6)
  {
    m_fish_x--;
    m_fish_y--;
  }
  else if (randDir == 7)
  {
    m_fish_x--;
  }
  else if (randDir == 8)
  {
    m_fish_x--;
    m_fish_y++;
  }

  return;
}
```

***aquaPenguin.h***

```
#ifndef AQUAPENGUIN_H
#define AQUAPENGUIN_H

// Forward Declarations to circumvent circular dependancy
class Sea;
class Fish;
class Killer_Whale;

class Penguin
{
  private:
    int m_peng_health;   // 0-100
    int m_peng_x;
    int m_peng_y;
    bool m_peng_alive;
  public:
    Penguin ();
    int getX () const {return m_peng_x;};
    int getY () const {return m_peng_y;};
    void setX (int new_x) {m_peng_x = new_x;};
    void setY (int new_y) {m_peng_y = new_y;};
    void move (Sea obj_sea, Fish arr_fish [], int arr_fish_size,
               Killer_Whale arr_kwhale [], int arr_kwhale_size);
};

#endif
```

***aquaPenguin.cpp***

```
#include "aquaClasses.h"
#include "aquaFish.h"
#include "aquaKillerWhale.h"
#include "aquaPenguin.h"
#include "aquaSea.h"
#include "aquaFunctions.cpp"

using namespace std;

Penguin::Penguin ()
{
  m_peng_health = rand () % (81 - 60) + 60;
  m_peng_x = -1;
  m_peng_y = -1;
  m_peng_alive = false;
}

void Penguin::move (Sea obj_sea, Fish arr_fish [], int arr_fish_size,
                    Killer_Whale arr_kwhale [], int arr_kwhale_size)
{
  int actuDistToFish = 8;
  int currDistToFish = 0;
  int tempMoveX = 0;
  int tempMoveY = 0;
  int amtMove = 0;
  int direction = 0;
  int fishIndex = 0;
  bool moveAwayKillerWhale = false;
  bool fishInRange = false;

  // Determine amount of cells to move in sea
  if (m_peng_health >= 81 && m_peng_health <= 100)
  {
    amtMove = 5;
  }
  else if (m_peng_health >= 61 && m_peng_health <= 80)
  {
    amtMove = 4;
  }
  else if (m_peng_health >= 41 && m_peng_health <= 60)
  {
    amtMove = 3;
  }
  else if (m_peng_health >= 21 && m_peng_health <= 40)
  {
    amtMove = 2;
  }
  else if (m_peng_health >= 1 && m_peng_health <= 20)
  {
    amtMove = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Chicken of the sea at: " << m_peng_x << " " << m_peng_y
         << endl;

    return;
  }

  // ADD: Find if any killer whales are near first and if so then penguin just moves away

  // Find if any fish are near <-- THIS IS WRONG, YOU NEED TO FIND THE CLOSEST FISH
  for (int i = 0; i < arr_fish_size; i++)
  {
    currDistToFish = calculate_distance (m_peng_x, m_peng_y,
                                         arr_fish[i]);
    if (currDistToFish <= 8)
    {
      if (currDistToFish < actuDistToFish)
      {
        actuDistToFish = currDistToFish;
        fishIndex = i;
        fishInRange = true;
      }
    }
  }

  // ADD: If fish and whale are found do something, we decide. Otherwise move randomly Peng See Dist 8.0

  // ADD Move 1 tick then gauge situation again
  for (int k = 0; k < amtMove; k++)
  {
    if (fishInRange == true && moveAwayKillerWhale == false)
    {
      tempMoveX = m_peng_x;    // temp used for storing before changing
      tempMoveY = m_peng_y;    // temp used for storing before changing
      direction = calculate_direction (m_peng_x, m_peng_y,
                                       arr_fish[fishIndex]);
      cout << "Penguin pos before moving: " << m_peng_x << ","
           << m_peng_y << endl;
      cout << "Closest Fish pos: " << arr_fish[fishIndex].getX () << ","
           << arr_fish[fishIndex].getY () << endl;

      if (m_peng_health == 0)
      {
        cout << "Chicken of the sea at: " << m_peng_x << " " << m_peng_y
             << endl;

        return;
      }
      if (direction == 1)
      {
        actuDistToFish--;
        m_peng_health--;
        tempMoveY++;
      }
      else if (direction == 2)
      {
        actuDistToFish--;
        m_peng_health--;
        tempMoveX++;
        tempMoveY++;
      }
      else if (direction == 3)
      {
        actuDistToFish--;
        m_peng_health--;
        tempMoveX++;
      }
      else if (direction == 4)
      {
        actuDistToFish--;
        m_peng_health--;
        tempMoveX++;
        tempMoveY--;
      }
      else if (direction == 5)
      {
        actuDistToFish--;
        m_peng_health--;
        tempMoveY--;
      }
      else if (direction == 6)
      {
        actuDistToFish--;
        m_peng_health--;
        tempMoveX--;
        tempMoveY--;
      }
      else if (direction == 7)
      {
        actuDistToFish--;
        m_peng_health--;
        tempMoveX--;
      }
      else if (direction == 8)
      {
        actuDistToFish--;
        m_peng_health--;
        tempMoveX--;
        tempMoveY++;
      }
      else
      {
        cout << "[ERROR]: Penguin direction messed up." << endl;
      }

      // MODIFY: Lastly check if out of bounds and then move peng
      if (tempMoveX > obj_sea.getWidth ()
          || tempMoveX < -(obj_sea.getWidth ()))
      {
        m_peng_x = m_peng_x;    // AKA dont move
        m_peng_y = m_peng_y;
      }
      else if (tempMoveY > obj_sea.getHeight ()
               || tempMoveY < -(obj_sea.getHeight ()))
      {
        m_peng_x = m_peng_x;    // AKA dont move
        m_peng_y = m_peng_y;
      }
      else
      {
        obj_sea.setCell (m_peng_x, m_peng_y, 'O'); // Delete old cell
        m_peng_x = tempMoveX;
        m_peng_y = tempMoveY;
        obj_sea.setCell (m_peng_x, m_peng_y, 'P'); // Set new cell
      }

      // Check if peng eats after moving
      if (actuDistToFish == 0)
      {
        // Stop moving
        amtMove = 0;
        // Eat fish
        m_peng_health += arr_fish[fishIndex].getFishAmtFood ();
        // ADD: Remove fish from grid
      }
      cout << "Penguin pos after moving: " << m_peng_x << ","
           << m_peng_y << endl;
    }
    else if (fishInRange == false && moveAwayKillerWhale == true)
    {

    }
    else if (fishInRange == false && moveAwayKillerWhale == false)
    {
      // If no fish, movement is random, else it's towards fish how ever many
      //    step the penguin can go
      direction = rand () % 8 + 1;
      if (direction == 1)
      {
        m_peng_y++;
      }
      else if (direction == 2)
      {
        m_peng_x++;
        m_peng_y++;
      }
      else if (direction == 3)
      {
        m_peng_x++;
      }
      else if (direction == 4)
      {
        m_peng_x++;
        m_peng_y--;
      }
      else if (direction == 5)
      {
        m_peng_y--;
      }
      else if (direction == 6)
      {
        m_peng_x--;
        m_peng_y--;
      }
      else if (direction == 7)
      {
        m_peng_x--;
      }
      else if (direction == 8)
      {
        m_peng_x--;
        m_peng_y++;
      }
      else
      {
        cout << "[ERROR]: Penguin random direction messed up." << endl;
      }
    }
  }

  return;
}
```

***aquaKillerWhale.h***

```
#ifndef AQUAKILLERWHALE_H
#define AQUAKILLERWHALE_H

class Penguin;

class Killer_Whale
{
  private:
    int m_kwhale_amt_pengs;
    int m_kwhale_x;
    int m_kwhale_y;
  public:
    Killer_Whale ();
    int getX () const {return m_kwhale_x;};
    int getY () const {return m_kwhale_y;};
    void setX (int new_x) {m_kwhale_x = new_x;};
    void setY (int new_y) {m_kwhale_y = new_y;};
    void move (Penguin arr_peng []);
};

#endif
```

***aquaKillerWhale.cpp***

```
#include "aquaClasses.h"
#include "aquaKillerWhale.h"
#include "aquaPenguin.h"

using namespace std;

Killer_Whale::Killer_Whale ()
{
  m_kwhale_x = -1;
  m_kwhale_y = -1;
}


void Killer_Whale::move (Penguin arr_peng [])
{

  return;
}
```

***aquaFunctions.cpp***

```
#include "aquaClasses.h"

using namespace std;

// Functions
template <typename TYPE>
int calculate_direction (int obj1_x, int obj1_y, TYPE obj2)
{
  int calculatedX = obj2.getX () - obj1_x;
  int calculatedY = obj2.getY () - obj1_y;
  int direction = 0;
  if (calculatedX == 0 && calculatedY > 0)
  {
    direction = 1;
  }
  else if (calculatedX > 0 && calculatedY > 0)
  {
    direction = 2;
  }
  else if (calculatedX > 0 && calculatedY == 0)
  {
    direction = 3;
  }
  else if (calculatedX > 0 && calculatedY < 0)
  {
    direction = 4;
  }
  else if (calculatedX == 0 && calculatedY < 0)
  {
    direction = 5;
  }
  else if (calculatedX < 0 && calculatedY < 0)
  {
    direction = 6;
  }
  else if (calculatedX < 0 && calculatedY == 0)
  {
    direction = 7;
  }
  else if (calculatedX < 0 && calculatedY > 0)
  {
    direction = 8;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "[ERROR]: Direction calculation failed." << endl;
  }

  return direction;
}

template <typename TYPE>
int calculate_distance (int obj1_x, int obj1_y, TYPE obj2)
{
  int distance = sqrt ((obj1_x - obj2.getX ())
                       * (obj1_x - obj2.getX ())
                       + (obj1_y - obj2.getY ())
                       * (obj1_y - obj2.getY ()));

  return distance;
}
```

Comment: I see `friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Sea obj);` is making a copy of your Sea object. The generated copy constructor you got from your compiler is unlikely to copy it the way you want it.  `friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Sea& obj);`  might be a quick fix.

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work as I still get the same variation of outputs.  

edit: I didn't try add the const. One sec.  

edit2: Ya that doesn't work either.

Comment: [Off topic]  Virtusal, you have nicely formatted source code.  I approve.

Comment: Thanks! I really do spend the effort to make it so and hearing it is actually enjoyable

Comment: You don't need to show us your entire project. Reduce the example to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): the smallest example that reproduces the problem you're having. This makes it easier for the people trying to solve your problem.

Comment: Well I specifically put in all bold that you don't need the code below it. I didn't want to edit it again to add all my code if others wanted to understand the issue better. It's very minimal but all of the post IS minimal because my "aquaSea.cpp" has INCLUDES that require all of the files that are below my bold statement.

Comment: What is MAX_SEA_GRID (it's not defined in the posted code)?

Comment: @mnistic my apologies, that’s actually the one file I didn’t add (aquaClasses.h) but it’s a constant int set to 25. Check back in 5.

Comment: The definitions of `calculate_distance` and `calculate_direction` are still missing, but with my stubs I am unable to reproduce your problem. What is your compiler?

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Works fine on my end. Sorry. The only thing I'm noticing is `if ((grid_size_height || grid_size_width) <= 0)` in aquaSea.cpp is wrong, you probably meant `if ((grid_size_height <= 0) || (grid_size_width) <= 0))` but that's not causing your problem.

Comment: So you're able to get a full 17x17 without any shorts and have values on the grid random each time you run?
Using MinGW btw

Comment: So I tested it with my compiler on my school computers and I can't replicate the issue either. So it has to be with something with my GNU I set up.